# Exec function make a call to a large number of processes

Tags: php, command, exec

So, here is my simple code:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    exec('php -q file.php ' . $i . ' > /dev/null &');
    echo 'Pros launched... ' . $i . '<br />';
}
?>
```

The problem its that every time I run this code its use mostly 100% of server resources and make the server go down... And that cause of call a so large number of processes with argv[1] == 0 ($i == 0)...

Any ideas?

Comment: Is file.php the same script as the one containing this code?

Comment: Unless there's a recursive relationship between the scripts, I don't see why it would happen. This script should just launch 2 processes, with arguments 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes, Indeed, But that what happen, Somehow...

Comment: What's there in `file.php`? maybe that is what bogs down your server

Comment: No, I think in that... And I make mostly a empty file, And the same result...

Comment: I will test in a VM and hope know the issue, I get done send tickets to reboot my server, Even SSH didn't response...